# Textnodes in list in columns don't respect parent width

Tags: html, css, text, overflow

A body of HTML, put in 3 columns, has list items with text nodes longer then their parent element.

The HTML is like so:

```
<div class='wrap'>
    <div class='column'>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      [...]
      <ul>
        <li>I'm a horribly long text node</li>
      </ul>
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The div.column is styled like so:

```
-ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
flex-basis: 0;
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
-ms-flex-positive: 1;
flex-grow: 1;
max-width: 100%; <-- this does it
position: relative;
width: 100%;
min-height: 1px;
columns: 3;
```

div.wrap:

```
display: -webkit-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
margin-right: -15px;
margin-left: -15px;
```

The text nodes in the li have a width 'as if' the div.column does not have max-width: 100%. It's their intrinsic width, so to speak. The li's however, do have a width not exceding their parent ul.

Result looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVL9N.png

I've tried fiddling with display, width, column-width, but to no avail.
There's no funky textwrapping CSS applied.

Here's the kicker: when I take out the textnode, and then re-apply it, the node is rendered as expected.

Q: Why does the text node exceed the width of the parent li?

A: Harm Smits posted the *fix* but my question was: why :)

Comment: Please add `class='wrap'` css too in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the following CSS property for your column:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```